# Python 3.3 installation ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, python

I have just installed ubuntu 3.10 and, although this version is still reliant on python 2 as the default, the python 3.3 interpreter is listed as installed in the software centre. Does this mean that python 3.3 is already here somewhere, and if so how do I access it to run my code?

I know there are many questions about installing python 3.3 alongside 2.7.x in Ubuntu (and definitely not replacing it!), but it seems to be already installed. However, in terminal I get 2.7.5 when I type 'python' and the online documentation says that it was not possible to break the reliance on python 2 for this ubuntu release. I was expecting to have to install it in a different directory, but if this has already been done then I could avoid messing with a critical bit of ubuntu.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use Python 3, run `python3` instead of just `python`. You can also use Python 3 for your scripts, if you add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

as the first line.

Comment: very helpful post! Is Python 3 default to 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

```
vic@vic-UX32VD ~/projects/mykde (master) $ which python
/usr/bin/python

vic@vic-UX32VD ~/projects/mykde (master) $ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 нояб. 23 06:52 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7

vic@vic-UX32VD ~/projects/mykde (master) $ ls -l /usr/bin/python3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 нояб. 23 06:52 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3892168 окт.   9 19:38 /usr/bin/python3.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3892168 окт.   9 19:38 /usr/bin/python3.3m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 нояб. 23 06:52 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.3m

vic@vic-UX32VD ~/projects/mykde (master) $
```

As you see when you type `python` `python2.7` is executed, because of the symlink.

If you need to run a Python script using Python3, either add shebang line to the beginning of your script: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (you then run it like `./a_script.py` given that you first made it executable using `chmod +x a_script.py1`) or run your script like `python3 a_script.py` (which is easier).